# Open Dictionary File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco-ios

I am trying to develop a Python script that will log into hundreds of Cisco IOS devices and configure them. The issue I am running into is that I do not want to define the device dictionary in the script itself, but have the script refer to a file (YAML?) and loop through the devices in the file. The script looks like this:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

R1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.122.71',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'cisco'
}

R2 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.122.82',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'cisco'
}


with open('snmp_configs.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
print (lines)

all_devices = [R1, R2]

for devices in all_devices:
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
    output = net_connect.send_config_set(lines)
    print (output)
```

As you can see I have R1 and R2 defined using dictionaries, but I don't want to add hundreds of device dictionaries in the script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either JSON or YAML format to store devices list and load the file in the script.

To use JSON format, create a file with .json extension, e.g. `devices.json` with following content:

```
[
   {
      "device_type":"cisco_ios",
      "ip":"192.168.122.71",
      "username":"admin",
      "password":"cisco"
   },
   {
      "device_type":"cisco_ios",
      "ip":"192.168.122.82",
      "username":"admin",
      "password":"cisco"
   }
]
```

To use YAML, do the same but this time with .yaml extension, e.g. `devices.yaml` with below content. To load this file you will need to install the `PyYAML` package (e.g. pip install PyYAML)

```
- device_type: cisco_ios
  ip: 192.168.122.71
  username: admin
  password: cisco
- device_type: cisco_ios
  ip: 192.168.122.82
  username: admin
  password: cisco
```

You can load the two files in the script like this:

```
import json
import yaml

# Load the json file
with open("devices.json") as f:
    all_devices = json.load(f)
    print(all_devices)

# Load the YAML file
with open("devices.yaml") as f:
    all_devices = yaml.safe_load(f)
    print(all_devices)

for device in all_devices:
    print(device)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dan!! This makes a lot of sense! Another question, how can I structure the For Loop to loop through the file, device by device? In the original script I am converting each Dict entry into a variable (R1, R2 etc) and referencing the variable in the loop. How can I tell the script to loop through each device entry in the YAML/JSON file? I truly appreciate your help! Again, I know Im fishing for answers here but I am also trying to learn this :)

Comment: Thanks so much Dan! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @ccsmooth, glad I could help. I have updated the code to include the loop.

Answer (score 0):

[ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) will get the job done. Like the JSON module, it's part of the standard library. It uses `ini` files.

devices.ini

```
[R1]
device_type = cisco_ios
ip = 192.168.122.71
username = admin
password = cisco
[R2]
device_type = cisco_ios
ip = 192.168.122.82
username admin
password cisco
```

Python code:

```
import configparser
#from netmiko import ConnectHandler

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('devices.ini')

devices = config.sections()

for device in devices:
    if config[device]['device_type'] == 'cisco_ios':
        print(device)
```

Comment: Thanks so much bfris.  I will see if I can incorporate this as well!